# PHP: LOCAL_LOG0 isn't recognized

Tags: php, ubuntu, rsyslog

I am working on Ubuntu (it use rsyslog), and I need to custom log some info with PHP. Here is my code:

```
openlog("mywebsite", LOG_PID | LOG_PERROR, LOG_LOCAL2);
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "mywebsite: 1000th visitor !");
closelog();
```

and I defined in `/etc/rsyslog/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` :

`local2.*            /var/log/apache2/mywebsite.log`

the file `mywebsite` is defined `chmod 777` but nothing appears in `mywebsite.log` but still in `error.log`

I found out that it's because PHP doesn't recognize `LOG_LOCAL2` or `LOG_LOCAL0`, in

```
openlog("mywebsite", LOG_PID | LOG_PERROR, LOG_LOCAL2);
```

I catch the error:

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: access in /var/www/default/public_html/index.php on line 6

despite it's defined in the offcial documentation: [PHP Official manual for openlog()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openlog.php)

PS: I am on PHP 5.3.10

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The error is about some `$access` variable yet I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: it's my full code exept the `<?php ?>`

Comment: If that is your full code how can PHP complain about line6?

Comment: I'm happy to learn that <html> </html> and text use PHP.

Comment: I'm happy to learn that `<html></html>` makes up a valid html document

Comment: @PeeHaa Actually you need a DOCTYPE and a title and a bunch of other stuff. Pierre you'll probably have better luck in askubuntu.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know askubuntu. Have a nice day